# Edge chromium won't show basic authentication popup?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, microsoft-edge, .htpasswd

I have an Apache server v2.4.43 that serves my website, and I use a simple .htpasswd that I call in .htaccess using the instruction "AuthUserFile <path to my .htpasswd file>" for my authentication.

Now the solution works with all browsers (a popup will be showed asking for a username/password), except for the Edge browser (based on Chromium build 84.0.522.52). It throws the following error before even showing the popup that asks you for your credentials:

```
Unauthorized

This server could not verify that you are authorized to access the document requested. Either you supplied the wrong credentials (e.g., bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Apache/2.4.43 (Unix) Server at mywebsite.com Port 443
```

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: I don’t have access to a current, chromium-based Edge right now … but I remember that older Internet Explorers had a setting in the Internet Options, whether asking for such credentials was allowed or not. Maybe the ChromEdge still has something similar, so I’d go look through the settings first of all here.

Comment: are you talking about Internet Properties -> security tab -> Enable Protected Mode?, if so i already disabled that mode but same error, and also my solution works if i use IE or Edge build 44

Comment: No, I’m talking about https://support.testsigma.com/support/solutions/articles/32000025042-how-to-enable-basic-authentication-for-internet-explorer-8-11-

Comment: always the same error

Comment: It might be some group policies of Edge browser which lead to the issue. I found a [similar thread](https://superuser.com/questions/978255/chrome-45-does-not-display-authentication-dialog) and you could refer to it. You could also check the [`AuthSchemes` policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#authschemes) of your Edge browser and set it properly. You can also check other related policies of [HTTP authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#http-authentication-policies) to see if there's something wrong.

Answer (score 11):

My organization encountered this today after deploying Chromium Edge at a test location for the first time. When we got with our Enterprise Support guys from MS, we found that the issue was our group policy settings; we needed to change `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\AuthSchemes` in the Windows Registry (`regedit.exe`) to add 'basic' ("ntlm,negotiate"->"basic,ntlm,negotiate").

(*We also subsequently discovered that under some circumstances, we needed to have that key not exist at all; when we removed it, Edge continued to work for sites that require basic authentication.*)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same Problem with Edge chromium and resolved it with the GPO Setting.
GPO: User Configuration -> Administrative Template -> Microsoft Edge -> HTTP Authentication
Policy: Supported authenticated schemes -> Enabled: basic,ntlm,negotiate

Earlier I only had NTLM,Negotiate: Which wasnt allowing the authentication Popups.

Comment: Yes, this is the same thing that we discovered; see my answer.